# How to get user_usergroup_map 'group_id' in Joomla 3.2.1

Tags: php, joomla3.0, usergroups

I need to output some content only available for a custom user group with id 10 (called Members). I found out how to get a default user group id in Joomla 3.2.1 with this code:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(); $usergroup = $user->getAuthorisedGroups();
if(in_array('10',$usergroup))
```

But when a registered customer is also in the new CUSTOM group 'Members' (map group_id = 10) I still get as output id '2' (= registered).

How do i get the `user_usergroup_map` 'group_id'? So the output would be `10` in my case.

Comment: Found out myself: $user = JFactory::getUser(); $groups = JUserHelper::getUserGroups($user->get('id')); if(!in_array('10',$groups))